# Multiple Configuration Files for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to extract some part of my Java web project and make it an independent library and then use that library in the project. The problem is that both the library and the web project use hibernate and have different hibernate.cfg.xml configuration files. How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can specify the location of the hibernate.cfg.xml when you build your SessionFactory

Comment: Can I have two different singleton classes with the same name in two different libraries? Otherwise, the naming of classes in different independent libraries should depend on each other.

Comment: Yes. In different packages it is possible.